# Why derivatives are set to zero for LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am looking through this code below:

```
class LstmParam:
    def __init__(self, mem_cell_ct, x_dim):
        self.mem_cell_ct = mem_cell_ct
        self.x_dim = x_dim
        concat_len = x_dim + mem_cell_ct
        # weight matrices
        self.wg = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len)
        self.wi = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len) 
        self.wf = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len)
        self.wo = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len)
        # bias terms
        self.bg = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
        self.bi = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
        self.bf = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
        self.bo = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
        # diffs (derivative of loss function w.r.t. all parameters)
        self.wg_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
        self.wi_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
        self.wf_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
        self.wo_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
        self.bg_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 
        self.bi_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 
        self.bf_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 
        self.bo_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 

    def apply_diff(self, lr = 1):
        self.wg -= lr * self.wg_diff
        self.wi -= lr * self.wi_diff
        self.wf -= lr * self.wf_diff
        self.wo -= lr * self.wo_diff
        self.bg -= lr * self.bg_diff
        self.bi -= lr * self.bi_diff
        self.bf -= lr * self.bf_diff
        self.bo -= lr * self.bo_diff
        # reset diffs to zero
        self.wg_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wg)
        self.wi_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wi) 
        self.wf_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wf) 
        self.wo_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wo) 
        self.bg_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bg)
        self.bi_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bi) 
        self.bf_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bf) 
        self.bo_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bo)
```

I don't understand why this is applying a derivative so early for `self.wg_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len))`. I'm not sure what is going on here. I am also confused why they are set to zero. If someone could explain why that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line such as

```
self.wg_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len))
```

is not *applying* a derivative, it is simply initializing an array that will later hold derivatives of the loss function with respect to values in the `wg` array.

In `apply_diff`, a gradient is applied here:

```
self.wg -= lr * self.wg_diff
```

**Crucially:** in-between calling the `__init__` function to create an instance of `LstmParam` and calling `apply_diff` to apply gradients, different code (that you are not showing) has to modify `self.wg_diff` so that it actually contains derivatives.

In order to compute gradients,

- A forward pass needs to use some data as input and compute an output where the computation involves the values in `wg`.
- The output is then compared with the desired correct output with a loss function.
- After computing the loss, a backward pass computes gradients (derivatives of the loss function with respect to all weights that are involved in computing the output). The backward pass fills `self.wg_diff` with actual values.

---

For completeness, this next line

```
self.wg_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wg)
```

is resetting the gradient array for the next backward pass.

Comment: @Mathis Muller thanks a lot. That is what I htought may be happening but wasnt sure. The whole code is very long (200 lines) so though i would just show the part in which i was confused on. So the apply_diff is changing the weighting according to the derivative and learning rate?

Comment: This is the code I am trying to understand https://github.com/Manik9/LSTMs/blob/master/lstm.py

Comment: @user218030 "So the apply_diff is changing the weighting according to the derivative and learning rate?" - yes. For each weight value in a weight array individually, what is subtracted from the weight is `learning_rate * gradient`.

Comment: @Muller Thanks. So basically each gate has its own weight that once the forward propagation happens then the derivative and learning rate are subtracted from the weight to get its new weight for each gate. One questions - Does this happen after one cell of the LSTM is complete or after all input has been inputed into each individual cell?

Comment: @user218030 I don't understand, sorry! "gate" and "cell" have a technical meaning in LSTMs, and I don't know what you mean by "one cell of the LSTM" and "each gate", and "all input".

Comment: Muller What I have read is the input goes into a "cell", and the cell contains gates. (forget,input,output, plus the tanh part). Then the output from the cell is passed onto the next cell (its recurrent I know, but im unwinding it for explaining purposes. The output for t-1 is used with the next input say x1 and then the output of that is used with x2 etc.

Comment: Could you maybe open a new post for those new questions? And since your new questions are not about programming, you could ask them on https://ai.stackexchange.com/.